# Disable StartIIS7Configuration transaciton on Uninstallation of Wix installer

Tags: iis, wix

I am having a problem with a Wix installer, that covers three different feature sets (Client / Developer and Server).

When Client is selected the installer does not need to perform any of the actions with IIS that are defined in components that aren't included within this feature.

On Installation I don't get a problem, as I have added a Custom Action

```
<!-- Only perform the IIS Configuration if we have installed the Admin Application-->
<Custom Action="SkipIISCA" Before="InstallValidate">
  <![CDATA[COMPONENT_TYPE = 2]]>
</Custom>
```

Which is only run when the "Client" component type is being installed. The custom action sets the SKIPCONFIGUREIIS property to 1

The problem occurs when either a Repair on an uninstall is executed on the installer. It appears that IIS Configuration is being attempted when the product is being uninstalled or repaired, and the custom action does not seem be run to disable this behaviour.

Is there a good way to set the SKIPCONFIGUREIIS setting on uninstallation / repair based on a Registry Setting ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the properties set during an installation are stored in the hidden windows directory, c:\windows\installer - one per installation. In the log of your uninstall/repair session, you can see that cached file opened up and properties being set for the new uninstall/repair session. (Alternatively, you can find this temp file from the uninstall/repair log, and open it with Orca. In Orca, under "Property", it will show the values of any install properties saved).

Based on the above description, I bet that the property that the custom action is being set is not stored, but that the value of COMPONENT_TYPE is available (The same input that was used to set SKIPCONFIGUREIIS in the custom action).

If so, then just make the IIS configuration action be based on these properties:

```
<Custom Action="Your_Configure_IIS_Action" Before="InstallFinalize">
(NOT SKIPCONFIGUREIIS ) OR (COMPONENT_TYPE = 2)</Custom>
```

If you don't want the ConfigureIIS to happen for any feature set during uninstall/repair, then just use these properties:

```
<Custom Action="Your_Configure_IIS_Action" Before="InstallFinalize">
(NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE) AND (REMOVE="ALL")</Custom>
```

Another thing to think about is if the original installer was at one level - e.g. a client, and the uninstall/repair is being done by someone at the server level. The component_type of the original install is stored. In that case, you might consider adding a check on how the component_type is determined (thru a dialog or some other attribute) during the uninstall/repair.